# How to get string variables to change and print out in a if loop

Tags: python, string, variables, if-statement, range

```
b=int(1)

if b == 1:
     b=2
     c = "on my thumb"
elif b== 2:
    b=3
    c = "on my shoe"
elif b== 3:
    b=4
    c = "on my knee"
elif b== 4:
    b+1
    c = "on my door"
elif b== 5:
    b+1
    c = "on my hive"
elif b== 6:
    b+1
    c = "on my sticks"
elif b== 7:
    b+1
    c = "up in heaven"
elif b== 8:
    b+1
    c = "on my gate"
elif b== 9:
    b+1
    c = "on my spine"
else:
    c = "once again"

for r in range(10):
    print("This old man, he played one He played knick-knack " + c +" Knick-knack paddywhack, give your dog a bone This old man came rolling home")
    b+1
```

Relatively new to coding so I don't really know what I am doing, but I am trying to get c to change every new time that r is printed....so that IT completes the old nursery rhyme. I am coding this in python...

Comment: Please read [ask] and maybe [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Change the print statement to `..." + r + "...`.  Assuming the old one compiled (no experience with whatever language this is) then the new one will print 1 the first time, 2 the second, 3 the third, etc.

Comment: You need to have the if else ladder in a loop. In the first run, the if condition will match and the rest of the ladder will be skipped

Comment: From the tag, it appears the language is python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parts = ["on my thumb", "on my shoe", ...]
numerators = ["one", "two", "three", ...]

for num, part in zip(numerators, parts):
    print "This old man, he played " + num
    print "He played knick-knack " + part
    print "Knick-knack paddywhack, give your dog a bone"
    print "This old man came rolling home"
```

Comment: I like this code, it's simple and effective...but what do I do to get the one to change +1 every time it is written out...can i use a simple if? or would it be more difficult than I am thinking

Comment: I do not quite understand. Why?

Comment: Like as the loop goes on, I would need it to say "This old man, he played two", "He played three" and so on and so forth, sorry I didn't word anything right...still half asleep

Answer (score 0):

Just store your strings in an array or list

```
lines = ["on my thumb", "on my shoe", "...."....]
```

and then iterate over that array (or list ) with the help of a for loop 
in c#-ish syntax:

```
foreach(line in lines)
{
  print("bla" + line + "blubb");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
string b[10] = {"on my thumb","on my shoe","on my knee","on my door","on my hive","on my sticks","up in heaven","on my gate","on my spine","once again"};

for (i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
   print("This old man, he played one He played knick-knack " + b[i] +" Knick-knack paddywhack, give your dog a bone This old man came rolling home.\n");
}
```

Since those values will not change you can create a static array to hold the values and then you can cycle through the contents while displaying the result.